# How do I restart paragraph indentation like the start of a new section?

Tags: sectioning, paragraphs, sections-paragraphs

I want to have

```
BIG TITLE

Property: Value
Property: Value
Property: Value

First paragraph is flush left.

    Second paragraph has the paragraph indent.
```

Instead I have

```
BIG TITLE

Property: Value
Property: Value
Property: Value

    First paragraph is not flush left.

    Second paragraph has the paragraph indent.
```

How can I restart paragraph indentation?

Comment: Please give details of your document class and other packages you loaded.  MWE is better.

Comment: Is that a list? Where are the paragraph breaks? That may be what you get, but how do you get it?

Comment: Well, how about attaching `\noindent` to the start of the first paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "restart" I take it you mean the way the first paragraph is not indented after `\chapter` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\parskip=\baselineskip

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstpar}{\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\parbox{\textwidth}{Property value\\Property value\\Property value}
\firstpar

First paragraph.

Second paragraph.
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]