# How to remove text indent for the first paragraph only?

Tags: formatting, indentation

Almost all templates I tried have an indentation for all paragraphs. How do I remove the spaces before the first paragraph only?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage[latin2]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{epic}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\usepackage[margin=2.6cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epstopdf} 

 \def\numset#1{{\\mathbb #1}}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{Th}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Lemma}[Th]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Cor}[Th]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Prop}[Th]{Proposition}

 \theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{Conj}[Th]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{Rem}[Th]{Remark}
\newtheorem{?}[Th]{Problem}
\newtheorem{Ex}[Th]{Example}

\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{im}}
\newcommand{\Hom}{{\rm{Hom}}}
\newcommand{\diam}{{\rm{diam}}}
\newcommand{\ovl}{\overline}
%\newcommand{\M}{\mathbb{M}}

\begin{document}

\title{example}
\begin{abstract}  a aaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaa aa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
\end{abstract}

\maketitle 

\section{Prelim} 
I was often using any of the available “lorem ipsum” generators on the web while testing different things in LaTeX until I discovered that the Latex distribution provides packages generating blind text, which is definitely more convenient. With just a few lines of code, these packages will generate paragraphes, even whole documents with sections, paragraphs of text, lists, etc.

The first package that I will introduce is the “blindtext” package. First the language option as well as the package have to be loaded. Make sure you get the order right, otherwise your text might appear in latin by default.
\medskip

\section*{Reference}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can put `\noindent` at the start of any paragraph to suppress the indent for that paragraph.

Comment: Normally LaTeX doesn't indent the first paragraph of sections, chapters, &c. Which class /package do you use?

Comment: Don't load `indentfirst`. That's what I use to get the non-default behaviour you describe.

Comment: @Bernard AMS math, IEEE, etc..

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328868/how-do-i-restart-paragraph-indentation-like-the-start-of-a-new-section/328914?s=14|0.0896#328914

Comment: If possible, please post a MWE...

Comment: @MadyYuvi What is a MWE and how to post it?

Comment: @HighGPA A "minimal working example": to post it, (1) take a LaTeX file that has the issue you mention (all paragraphs including the first are indented), (2) make it as short as possible (have as little text as possible that still shows the issue, remove packages as long as they don't affect the issue), (3) edit this question to include the LaTeX source and optionally a screenshot of the typeset output.

Comment: @cfr Apart from `indentfirst`, I think it might also be language-specific babel/polyglossia modules that follow their respective typographic style, according to egreg's answer at [No indent in the first paragraph in a section?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section/39232#39232)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I hope the update is clear enough. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: @HighGPA: No. Update your question with code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and remove all the stuff that you see has no impact on your output (which could be considered extraneous to the problem).

Comment: @HighGPA: ...thanks for adding `\end{document}`. You still have a bunch of unnecessary stuff included in your code that does not pertain to the problem. Do you use any theorems? No. So remove that content. Do you use `\ovl` anywhere? No. So remove that. What about `\im` or `\Hom` or...? No. So remove that as well. Do you need an `abstract` or a `\title` and the accompanying `\maketitle`? No. Why? Because it has nothing to do with the indentation of a paragraph. What about packages like `pict2e` or `epic` or `graphicx` or...? Remove them, since they have nothing to do with the problem...

Comment: @HighGPA: ...once you trim down all the unnecessary stuff, you'll see that you're using [`indentfirst`](//ctan.org/pkg/indentfirst) which does exactly what it states - it indents the first paragraph after a section. If you had gone through the process of providing a [minimal example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764), you would most likely have identified this as the problem.

Comment: Since the code is not minimal, i can tell that you are either a user for over twenty years and never updated your knowledge, or were looking for a template and got a really outdated one. Templates are like used cars, you never know what you are buying when don't kbow anything about cars.

Comment: Off-Topic: `t1enc` is a compatibility package only. You should replace it by `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. You don't need to load `graphics` after `graphicx`. Almost nobody uses `epic` for decades. Even the extended `eepic` is outdated. In our days, we use `tikz` or `pstricks`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke This is why I am seeking help.. Thanks for comments.

Comment: In this case: Don't use (outdated) templates you do not understand. Start with a minimal document and add only those packages you need. BTW: `amsart` already includes most AMS-packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Creating community-wiki post to move answer out of comments.)*

By default, LaTeX does not indent the first paragraph of sections, chapters, etc. This can be overriden by certain [language-specific styles (with the *babel* package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39227/no-indent-in-the-first-paragraph-in-a-section/39232#39232), or by loading the `indentfirst` package, as you have done here.

So if you don't want the first paragraph indented, don't load the `indentfirst` package: remove this line:

```
\usepackage{indentfirst}
```